# Scope of macro puzzle

Tags: c++, macros

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sum(){
#define SUM(a,b) a+b
}

int main(void){
   int a = 10; 
   int b = 20; 
   int c = SUM(a,b);
   int d = MUL(a,b);
   cout << c << endl;
   cout << d << endl;
   return 0;
}


void mul(){
#define MUL(a,b) a*b
}
```

The problem gives an error with MUL macro. But runs fine with SUM macro. Why is this happening?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Notice that one is expanded _below_ its definition and one is expanded _above_ its definition.

Comment: I have never seen this mix of a function and a define. But why ?

Comment: 1. Don't use macros. 2. Macros don't know about scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you define the `SUM` macro before calling it.

It does not have anything to do with the fact that it is defined in a function, i.e. it is accessible on the entire file, bellow its definition.

Comment: even after declaring mul() function **before** main(). It is giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Macros know nothing about function scope. The scope of a macro starts at the `#define` and ends at an `#undef` or the end of the compilation unit, whichever happens first.

To use a macro, the code must be in the macro's scope - like the `SUM` macro in the example.

The `MUL` macro is not expanded inside `main`, because its `#define` has not been seen yet. A macro can not be forward declared, just `#define`'d, and declaring the function "containing" the macro has nothing to do with macro scope.